# Как запустить go код на vds ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, golang, vds

Я купил vds с ОС ubuntu, и скачал туда go. Но возник вопрос-как мне запустить мой проект на golang в сервере правильно? Я запускаю go файл через go run main.go, там вывод Println работает, а вывод на страницу нет
код:

```
    package main
import (
     "github.com/gorilla/mux"
      "net/http"
    "fmt"
)
func setDefaultHeaders(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "helloooooooo")
   }
func main() {
    fmt.Println("helloooooo")
    r := mux.NewRouter()

   r.HandleFunc("/", setDefaultHeaders)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r)
}
```

Comment: залить на сервер исходники, сбилдить и запустить. Или сбилдить  у себя, залить бинарь на сервер и запустить. не так?

Comment: Прописать ``go [путь к файлу с программой]``

Comment: @ДенисОрлов ошибка main.go is not in GOROOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скопируйте ваш `main.go` на сервер в какой-нибудь каталог. Пусть для определённости это будет `~/tmp/stackoverflow`.

Теперь в этом каталоге подготовьте окружение и скомпилируйте приложение:

```
cd ~/tmp/stackoverflow
go mod init example.org/server
go mod tidy
go build ./
```

В результате в каталоге `~/tmp/stackoverflow` появится исполнимый файл `server`. Это бинарник вашей программы.

Имя модуля `example.org` выбрано мной "от балды". Вы можете назвать ваш модуль как угодно. Бинарник по умолчанию получит имя, стоящее после крайнего `/` в имени модуля.

Ссылки:

- [Тьюториал: Модули в Go](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/create-module)
- [go mod init](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-init)
- [go mod tidy](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy)
- [go build](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies)

Comment: `go mod download` еще надо

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но все еще не выводится в браузере( Ошибка в firefox:  SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Comment: @righty_dev вы открываете ссылку как `https`? Это неверно. У вас сервер HTTP: [http://localhost:8000/](http://localhost:8000/) Я сейчас проверил - работает.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor необязательно. `go build` сам выкачивает все зависимости, указанные в `go.sum`